# Does ...Rxe3+ work for Black?

Tags: analysis

In the position below, does `...Rxe3+` sacrifice work for Black?
I need concrete lines, that prove your claims, I can not satisfy myself with some rough evaluation.

Thank you. Regards.

```
[Title "Black to move"]
[StartFlipped "0"]
[fen "2krr3/ppp2ppp/3b1n2/8/6P1/2NPB3/PPP1KPq1/R2Q2R1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Rxe3+
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This looks like a 'no engines' question, otherwise ALNS would have just used Stockfish. Be afraid, B-player analysis is happening!

```
[FEN "2krr3/ppp2ppp/3b1n2/8/6P1/2NPB3/PPP1KPq1/R2Q2R1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Rxe3 2.Kxe3 Re8+ 3.Kd2 Bf4
```

```
[FEN "2krr3/ppp2ppp/3b1n2/8/6P1/2NPB3/PPP1KPq1/R2Q2R1 b - - 0 1"]

1...Rxe3 2.Kxe3 Re8+ 3.Ne4 Rxe4+ 4.dxe4 Qxe4+ 5.Kd2 Bf4+ 6.Kc3 Nd5+ 7.Kb3 Qb4#
```

```
[FEN "2krr3/ppp2ppp/3b1n2/8/6P1/2NPB3/PPP1KPq1/R2Q2R1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rxe3 2.Kxe3 Re8+ 3.Ne4 Rxe4+ 4.Kd2 Bf4+ 5.Kc3 Nd5+ 6.Kb3 Qxf2 7.dxe4 Qb6+ 8.Kc4 Ne3+
```

```
[Title "White survives, sort of"]
[FEN "2krr3/ppp2ppp/3b1n2/8/6P1/2NPB3/PPP1KPq1/R2Q2R1 b - - 0 1"]

1... Rxe3 2.Kxe3 Re8+ 3.Ne4 Rxe4+ 4.Kd2 Bf4+ 5.Kc3 Nd5+ 6.Kb3 Qxf2 7.a3 Qb6+ 8.Ka2 Be5 9.c3 Nxc3+ 10.bxc3 Bxc3 11.Rg2 Qe6+ 12.Qb3 Re2+ 13.Rxe2 Qxe2+ 14.Kb1 Qxd3+ {After this Black is able to trade the pieces and have a deadly pawn majority on both sides of the board, and an extra piece. Further play was very computery so I didn't post it.}
```

```
[Title "Stockfish calls it a win"]
[FEN "2krr3/ppp2ppp/3b1n2/8/6P1/2NPB3/PPP1KPq1/R2Q2R1 b - - 0 1"]

 1... Rxe3+ 2.Kxe3 Re8+ 3.Ne4 Rxe4+ 4.Kd2 Nd5 {Here's the killer. The knight closes the luft on c3} 5.dxe4 Qxf2+ 6.Qe2 (6.Kc1 Bf4+ 7.Kb1 Nc3+ 8.bxc3 Qb6#) Bf4+ {Now Black strips the Queen's defender} 7.Kd1 Ne3+ 8.Kd2 Nxg4+ 9.Kc3 Qxe2 10.Rge1 Bd2+ 11.Kd4 Qf2+ 12.Kd5 c6+ 13.Kc4 Ne5+ 14.Kb3 Qb6+ 15.Ka3 Qb4#
```

Comment: I do not have access to Stockfish, that is why I have posted here... It is OK to use engines as I actually want to know if Black wins with the sacrifice. I have upvoted your answer, mainly because I have missed `a3! + Ka2` in my analysis, otherwise I have come to the same conclusions as you have.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff Stockfish says it's a crush.  I ran it after I did my work above ;-)  I'll post it in a few moments.

Comment: Thank you! Please take time, its 3 AM here and I soon must go to sleep. Thank you for your efforts, I really appreciate it!

Comment: That `...Nd5!` intermediate move, sacrificing the queen, was fantastic! I missed that in my calculations. I have already upvoted, and now I am officially accepting your answer. Thanks! Best regards until next time.

Comment: @AlwaysLearningNewStuff You are aware that Stockfish is a free download, and that you can plug it into most chess interfaces (even free ones like Babaschess). Also you can upload games and positions and do online Stockfish anlysis on the web through lichess.org (free)

Comment: @SimenS: I know Stockfish is free, but I have no time to install it at the moment because I have no chess interface ( I used Fritz in the old days ). I just have a lot of other things to do. I did not know about lichess, I will try it out... Thanks.

Comment: In the final line, it appears that White's king can escape to b1 by 5.dxe4 Qxf2+ 6.Kc1

Comment: @RickG 6... Bf4+ 7. Kc1 Nc3+ 8. bxc3 Qb6#